# jQuery.inArray() function doesn't work correctly in beforeShowDay function of jQuery-ui DatePicker

Tags: laravel, jquery-ui, datepicker

I try to highlight an array of dates, that are saved in the DB, by changing their class. For this goal I use beforeShowDay function, and I've tried literally every solution on  Stack Overflow. Even some of them looked very logical, everytime something get wrong.

I use Laravel and jQuery to accomplish the goal. I also use multiDatesPicker extension of jQuery-ui DatePicker.

Here is my input field:

```
<input required type="text" name="dates" id="datepicker" class="form-control">
```

My **sript**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var openDates = @json($open_dates);

  $( "#datepicker" ).multiDatesPicker({
     beforeShowDay: function (date) {
       if ($.inArray(date, openDates) !== -1) {
           return [true, 'open-date'];
       }else {
           return [true, ''];
       }
     }
  });
});
```

And the code in the **controller**:

```
$open_dates_raw = ExcursionDate::where('excursion_id', $excursion->id)->get();
$open_dates = array();
foreach ($open_dates_raw as $d) {
  $open_dates[] = $d->date; /*It is a DATE, not DATETIME column*/
}

return view("view.name", [
                   ...
                   'open_dates' => $open_dates,
                   ... ]);
```

Basically, I think something within **$.inArray(date, openDates)** isn't working because I've tried many different options and it still didn't find a match.

When I console.log the **date** variable in beforeShowDay I get this:

```
...
Tue Mar 30 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (EEST)
...
```

When I console.log the **openDates** variable it shows an array which looks like this:

```
(4) ["2021-03-10 00:00:00", "2021-03-17 00:00:00", "2021-03-24 00:00:00", "2021-03-31 00:00:00"]
```

I've also tried to manipulate this output from the controller getting:

```
(4) ["2021-03-10 ", "2021-03-17", "2021-03-24", "2021-03-31"]
```

or even this:

```
(4) ["2021-3-10 ", "2021-3-17", "2021-3-24", "2021-3-31"]
```

So now getting back to the script - I've tried different options like

```
if ($.inArray(date.toString(), openDates) !== -1)
```

or even

```
if ($.inArray(openDates, date) !== -1)
```

I've also tried changing the controller:

```
$open_dates = ExcursionDate::where('excursion_id', $excursion->id)->pluck('date');
```

but still nothing...

Any thoughts?

Comment: is it type string or date ?  do typeof date and typeof openDates[0]

Comment: Hi @Frenchy, thanks for your attention! 
Date is an object, openDates is an object, openDates[0] is a string.

Comment: you have to use same format for Date and openDates dates. so openDates is an objet could you display the json open_date you receive (i suppose from server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i dont know exactly the format of your openDates, but i know values inside are string, so i convert date to string like this:

```
  beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    var str_date = $.datepicker.formatDate( "yy-mm-dd", date);
    //console.log(str_date);
    if ($.inArray(str_date, openDates) !== -1) {
      return [true, 'open-date'];
    } else {
      return [true, ''];
    }
  }
```

you could change the format following the format of dates inside openDates

Comment: Thank you, @Frenchy! This solved my problem! I gave you "This answer is useful", but my reputation is still low for you to see the point. However thank you again! :)